# How to make a query in PostgreSQL with the text in Upper()

Tags: c#, postgresql, select

***Coding in C#

This works:

```
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conx.getConexion());
        conn.Open();     
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("Select \"NombreMarca\" From \"Marca\" Where \"NombreMarca\" ='"+cbMarca.Text.ToLower()+"'", conn);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
```

//cbMarca is a ComboBox

Now, this doesnt:

```
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conx.getConexion());
        conn.Open();     
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("Select \"NombreMarca\" From \"Marca\" Where \"NombreMarca\" ='"+cbMarca.Text.ToUpper()+"'", conn);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
```

And i need it in upper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to compare all values with the string supplied or do you want to filter out all upper cased strings?

For a just comparing the values against each other try changing the column to upper case as well:

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("Select NombreMarca From Marca Where UPPER(NombreMarca) ='"+cbMarca.Text.ToUpper()+"'", conn);
```

Comment: That does not seem to be what the OP asks for.

Comment: Every field in the table is uppercased. And i need that the text in the cb to be upper so i can compare, cuz if it is not exactly the same(uppers and lowers), even if its already on the table, i get nothing. Thats why im using upper

Comment: Then it is a bit more of a mystery. Do you get the same result using PostgreSQL UPPER function instead of the C# one, ie: Select NombreMarca From Marca Where UPPER(NombreMarca) =UPPER('"+cbMarca.Text+"')"

Comment: The MixedCaseIdentifiers are not needed, and the quoting of TheColumnNames in the Query makes it overly complex, IMHO. And there is also http://xkcd.com/327/